# Change dimensions of AnythingSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, anythingslider

I'm trying to change the dimensions of the above slider from css-tricks.

I might likely be missing something obvious or making an amateur mistake but I cannot find the styling rules for it.  I've read the details over at css-tricks and they suggest changing the css.  There is no width setting in the css.

I've looking with an inspector and the Div seems to be created in a JS function.  I tried to decipher it and backtrack to find where the values were being set but I couldn't.

Does anyone know the answer please?

Comment: please post here the the html structure and script you have used

Comment: @Spokey There's far too much to paste.  I was hoping someone who had also downloaded the plugin might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the size of the parent div, in the case of the demo: `anythingSlider`.

```
#anythingSlider {width:450px !important, height:240px !important}
```

Comment: I tried that.  There's also a part of the css that says "Set dimensions here" but nothing changes.  It's like it's being overwritten.

Comment: Are you using any Web Development tools with your browser? Why don't you investigate where the CSS is coming from on that element?

Comment: I have, that was one of the first things I did.  The styling is not coming from a css sheet.  It's inline and looks to be populated from the js function.